# change returned field based on comparison (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a numerical PHP variable, call it $a, and a MySQL table with a key column and two columns called z and y.

Column z can contain a number or NULL. Column y already contains either the words MOD or LGM or might be NULL.

I would like to query the table and return all the fields that match the key but also I would like to compare the field's z number to $a: if it is >= $a I want to set the field's returned values of y to LGM. If it is < $a I want to set the field's returned value of y to MOD. If z is NULL I just want to leave the returned field's value of y as is.

Can anyone help me with designing the basic SQL query string (if indeed it is possible), I'm OK with the interfacing between PHP and MySQL.
Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using function IF: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

```
if( z is null, null, if( z >= ?, 'LGM', 'MOD' ) )
```

in place of '?' put your value of $a

Comment: Thanks very much. Are we talking something like: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE key = some_value IF (z is NULL, NULL, IF(z >= some_other_value y='LGM' ELSE y='MOD')).  Note the y= assignment. Is it possible to do that -overwrite the usual y column based on the comparison with z? I'm trying to work with the excellent MySQL MAN pages but it's a bit hard for me at this stage.